# What should be used for multiple authentication in swagger (anyOf or oneOf)?

Tags: authentication, swagger, openapi

I'm developing validation against a swagger schema. I have a question regarding multiple authentications, imagine I have a security block

```
security:
 - header
 - cookie
```

Logic is like this - parse a user request, and put header/cookie inside some hashmap/dict `V`.

- If a user has provided no header/cookie - return an error
- If a user has provided the only header, add header value to `V`, `V["header"] = request.header.value`
- If a user has provided the only cookie, add cookie value to `V`, `V["cookie"] = request.cookie.value`

But what should I do if a user has provided both cookie and header? Should I return an error (oneOf) or put the only header to the `V` variable (depends on the order of security) or put both header and cookie in the `V` or it depends on the application logic?

I have read https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/, but it is still unclear to me.

Comment: Putting it as a comment as I am not 100% sure, but I'd say it depends on your application needs. The `OpenAPI` specification allows you to enforce an `AND` or an `OR` for authentication, but (as far as I know) leaves open whether to allow only 1 or more auth types internally. You could always return a `Bad Request` response.

Comment: FYI this is being discussed in the OpenAPI Specification repository here: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1698

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Swagger/OpenAPI multiple security requirements and side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42679595/113116)